# psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "user1"

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm getting the followign error when trying to connect to postgres database from a vm:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user1"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user1"
```

I've created the user

```
CREATE USER user1 WITH PASSWORD 'pass1';
```

and added the following to my pg_hba.conf file

```
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
local   all             postgres                                md5
```

but when using `pscopg2.connect()` and specifying the dbname, user, password, port and host, I'm still getting the same error

for reference, when trying to connect to the server using psql on the vm I get the following error:

```
psql --host=localhost --port=5432 --username=user1 --dbname=postgres
Password for user user1:
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user1"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user1"
```

please let me know if more info is needed!

Comment: Either: 1) You are supplying the wrong password or 2) You are connecting to the wrong Postgres cluster.

Comment: You are saying: '... connect to the server using psql on the **vm**'. Probably your VM and host OS got different IP addresses.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer how can I connect to the postgres database from the vm?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver how can I check which postgres cluster I'm connecting to?

Comment: @Ethan: Check the IP addresses and if they are different add a correct entry in `pg_hba.conf`

Comment: If you don't already have them enabled, then enable `log_connections` and `log_disconnections` in `postgresql.conf`.  Then check the log file(s) to see which cluster you are attempting the connection to.